# angular 11 ngmodel not binding to select

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 11/TypeScript project I have the following model:

```
export interface Opponent {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    beltRank: BeltRankEnum;
    heightInInches: number;
    weightInLbs: number;    
}

export enum BeltRankEnum {
    White = 1,
    Blue = 2,
    Purple = 3,
    Brown = 4,
    Black = 5
}

const WHITE = "WHITE"
const BLUE = "BLUE"
const PURPLE = "PURPLE"
const BROWN = "BROWN"
const BLACK = "BLACK"

export const BeltRankToLabelMapping : Record<BeltRankEnum, string>  = {
    [BeltRankEnum.White]: WHITE,
    [BeltRankEnum.Blue]: BLUE,
    [BeltRankEnum.Purple]: PURPLE,
    [BeltRankEnum.Brown]: BROWN,
    [BeltRankEnum.Black]: BLACK,
}

export const LabelToBeltRankMapping = {
    WHITE: BeltRankEnum.White,
    BLUE: BeltRankEnum.Blue,
    PURPLE: BeltRankEnum.Purple,
    BROWN: BeltRankEnum.Brown,
    BLACK: BeltRankEnum.Black,
}
```

My component is:

```
    public opponent: Opponent = null;
    beltRankToLabelMapping = BeltRankToLabelMapping;
    labelToBeltRankMapping = LabelToBeltRankMapping;
    beltRanks = Object.values(BeltRankEnum).filter(f => !isNaN(Number(f)))
```

html snippet:

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="beltRankLabel" for="beltRank">Belt Rank</label>
                <select [(ngModel)]="labelToBeltRankMapping[opponent.beltRank]">
                    <option *ngFor="let beltRank of beltRanks" 
                            [ngValue]="beltRank"> {{beltRankToLabelMapping[beltRank]}} </option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

The problem I'm having is that the drop down is not showing the beltRank Value for opponent. It's showing blank. Also, when I select an option from the drop down it's not setting it on the opponent model. Does anyone know what's going wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try changing [ngValue] to [value]

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately that did not work [dolig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7592083/dolig)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that can be your ngValue, that need to be changed to:

```html
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="beltRankLabel" for="beltRank">Belt Rank</label>
                <select [(ngModel)]="labelToBeltRankMapping[opponent.beltRank]">
                    <option *ngFor="let beltRank of beltRanks" 
                            [value]="beltRank"> {{beltRankToLabelMapping[beltRank]}} </option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Edit:

The real problem in your code was that the select needs a name to receive a data in ngModel. Look this:

```html
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="beltRankLabel" for="beltRank">Belt Rank</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="opponent.beltRank" name="beltRank">
                    <option *ngFor="let beltRank of beltRanks" 
                            [value]="beltRank"> {{beltRankToLabelMapping[beltRank]}} </option>
                </select>
      </div>
```

And I did a small change in ngModel passing "opponent.beltRank" to record the variable

Comment: Hi [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9927579/gabriel-sereno). Unfortunately, I still see the same behavior

Comment: [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9927579/gabriel-sereno) Here is the link. Thanks!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-35lvw3

Comment: Sorry for my late answer but here is the correction: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zkfph3?file=src/app/opponent-details.component.html

Comment: Thanks so much [Gabriel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9927579/gabriel-sereno). That worked!